# Remeber Me C# app setting

Tags: c#, authentication

I Create login form and want to put "remember me" check box on it.
But every time i open program it doesn't change.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        Project.Properties.Settings.Default.rememberMe = true;
        Project.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    else
    {
        Project.Properties.Settings.Default.rememberMe = false;
        Project.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Also i want to save user login information, should i save them in app setting just like remember me setting or there is better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saving the settings, but you need to retrieve those settings too.

Subscribe to the Form's load event and set the value of the CheckBox.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.Checked = Project.Properties.Settings.Default.rememberMe;
}
```

Also, and this is just common practice, but your code could be shorter:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Project.Properties.Settings.Default.rememberMe = checkBox1.Checked;
    Project.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```